# Text in the page converts automatically to wikipedia links

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Some text in the body of sharepoint automatically converts itself to wikipedia links without adding a link.

Is there some feature that we can disable to make it stop ?

Comment: Have you looked at it from another PC or other browser? It sounds like you have a browser add-in or accelerator.

Comment: should you post a sample from this text ?! are you using any CSS / HTML tags within the page ?